# Get Modified By on Table Update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Is it possible to get the user that modified a row in a db. I can get the `ModifiedOn` Date. My code below;

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgUpdate
ON Table1
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0   RETURN
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(object_ID('trgUpdate')) > 1  RETURN;
SET NOCOUNT  ON;



UPDATE Table1
SET    ModifiedOn = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM   Table1 c
       INNER JOIN INSERTED i
         ON c.accID = i.accID
END
```

Comment: The database doesn't store this in a table, unless you have an explicit column with the information.  It may also be stored in the log file (if you have full logging on) or in an audit table.

Comment: Please check the solution at [SQL Server Log Tool for Capturing Data Changes](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/log-data-changes-using-change-data-capture-for-sql-server-2005.aspx) where a basic trigger structure is used for tables whose data is considered as sensitive and traced for changes to log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify which columns are altered after an insert, update, delete command on a table within a [SQL trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx), you can use apply logic

```
create trigger tr_DataTable on DataTable after update, insert, delete
as
begin

select
    ColumnA = case when i.ColumnA = d.ColumnA then 'not changed' else 'changed' end,
    ColumnB = case when i.ColumnB = d.ColumnB then 'not changed' else 'changed' end
from inserted i
full outer join deleted d on i.ColumnA = d.ColumnA

end
```

In this sample I assumed the ColumnA is the PK field of the DataTable table
If **inserted** field value differs from **deleted** field value then this shows data on related field is updated

Although SQL provide a means of determining updated columns using [Columns_Updated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx), it is bitwise and I find it difficult to apply. So I prefer above logic

```
alter trigger tr_DataTable on DataTable after update, insert, delete
as
begin

select
    FirstColumn = case when COLUMNS_UPDATED() & 2^0 = 0 then 'not changed' else 'changed' end,
    SecondColumn = case when COLUMNS_UPDATED() & 2^1 = 0 then 'not changed' else 'changed' end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Table1` has a `ModifiedBy` column, then this should work

```
UPDATE Table1
SET    ModifiedOn = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       ModifiedBy = SUSER_SNAME()
FROM   Table1 c
       INNER JOIN INSERTED i
         ON c.accID = i.accID
```

Comment: Many Thanks, Is it possible then to find which columns were `Modified`?